# How to count a field if value is not null in elasticsearch

Tags: python-3.x, elasticsearch

I have indexed some documents in ElasticSearch.
Short view looks like this:

```
{
  "tenant_id":"abcd1234"
  "provider_id":"3456"
   .
   .
   .
   "doctor_summary": ["line1", "line2", "line3"] OR it could be null.
}
```

I want to calculate this list as 1 if not null,

```
     query_template = {

        "bool":{
            "must":[
                {"term":{"tenant_id.keyword":tenant_id}},
                {"term":{"provider_id.keyword":provider_id}},
                {"range":{"visit_date":{"gte":from_date,"lte":to_date}}},
                
            ],
            "filter":[]
        
        }
    }



aggs_query = {
   "doctor_summary_count":{
            "value_count":{"field":"doctor_summary.keyword"}
        }
}    

res = CLIENT.search(index = config['elasticsearch']['abcd'],
                        query = query_template,
                        size = 10000,
                        aggs = aggs_query)
```

After calling this aggregation query, it gives result as ( size of the list * total doctor_summary field).

For example: the result of above query on above document should be 1. (As it is not null).
But it gives as 3(because list contains 3 lines.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [exist query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-exists-query.html) in aggregation with [filter aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html).

**Query:**

```json
{
  "aggs": {
    "count": {
      "filter": {
       "exists": {
         "field": "doctor_summary.keyword"
       }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Response:**

```json
"aggregations" : {
    "count" : {
      "doc_count" : 1
    }
  }
```